# How to add an icon to a QGroupBox title?

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to add an icon (programmatically, via QtCreator, with or without a stylesheet) to the QGroupBox title?

I want to place a mark close to the title of some of the QGroupBoxes in my GUI. The best place would be to the right of the title, but any other reasonable position (to the left of the title, or in the top right corner of the widget) could be also valid.

The only way I could think of is creating a QLabel with an icon and visually placing it on top of the QGroupBox, in the desired position. But I find this an ugly solution.

**Edit**

I know there is a way of setting the `indicator` used for *checkable* QGroupBoxes, as any image, both for checked and unchecked states, using stylesheets. But then the QGroupBox must be checkable, etc.  I want to add this mark (a small image) independently to the *checkability* of the QGroupBox.

Comment: _I want to place a mark_ do you mean a check mark?

Comment: No, sorry. I meant some small image. As an example: if I don't get a way to do it, at the end I will append an asterisk (*) to the end of the title... But I would like to have the possibility of adding any small image (a blue dot, a red diamond, a green star, ...)

Comment: I see. Because a check mark is pretty easy to add. An image is already a challenge. But I am on it and I hope I would be able to give you a solution soon.

Comment: Please, take a look at [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmBzK.png) and let me know if it is suitable for you. If you want to adjusted it somehow, just tell me and I will do it for you. Then I will post the solution.

Comment: It looks promising! That will be suitable for me, of course!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Background

Unfortunatelly, `QGroupBox` does not have a `setIcon` method, as `QPushButton` does.

A possible solution could be to make `QGroupBox` checkable using [`QGroupBox::setCheckable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#checkable-prop) and set a custom image as an indicator using a [stylesheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qgroupbox) like this:

```
QGroupBox::indicator:unchecked {
    image: url(:/images/checkbox_unchecked.png);
}
```

However, this will make the whole group box disabled, when the checkbox is unchecked.

## Solution

Having this background in mind, I would suggest you a fairly complex, but also a pretty flexible solution, consisting of the following steps:

1. Subclass [`QStyleOptionGroupBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptiongroupbox.html) and declare additional variables as public class attributes:

   ```
   QPixmap pixmap;
   int offset;
   int leftSpace;
   int rightSpace;
   ```

   These will be used for passing the decoration pixmap, as well as the placement settings, to the style.
2. Subclass `QCommonStyle` and reimplement [`QCommonStyle::drawComplexControl`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommonstyle.html#drawComplexControl) like this:

   ```
   if (const StyleOptionDecoratedGroupBox *groupBox = qstyleoption_cast<const StyleOptionDecoratedGroupBox *>(opt)) {
       QRect textRect = proxy()->subControlRect(CC_GroupBox, opt, SC_GroupBoxLabel, widget);
       QRect checkBoxRect = proxy()->subControlRect(CC_GroupBox, opt, SC_GroupBoxCheckBox, widget);
       int decorationOffset = 0;
       int pixmapRectWidth = 0;
       int pixmapHeight = 0;
       int textOffset = 0;

       if (!groupBox->pixmap.isNull()) {
           decorationOffset = groupBox->offset;
           pixmapRectWidth = groupBox->leftSpace
                           + groupBox->pixmap.width()
                           + groupBox->rightSpace;
           pixmapHeight = groupBox->pixmap.height();
           textOffset = decorationOffset + pixmapRectWidth;
       }

       textRect.adjust(textOffset, 0, textOffset, 0);

       // Draw frame
       if (groupBox->subControls & QStyle::SC_GroupBoxFrame) {
           QStyleOptionFrame frame;
           frame.QStyleOption::operator=(*groupBox);
           frame.features = groupBox->features;
           frame.lineWidth = groupBox->lineWidth;
           frame.midLineWidth = groupBox->midLineWidth;
           frame.rect = proxy()->subControlRect(CC_GroupBox, opt, SC_GroupBoxFrame, widget);
           p->save();
           QRegion region(groupBox->rect);
           if (!groupBox->text.isEmpty()) {
               bool ltr = groupBox->direction == Qt::LeftToRight;
               QRect finalRect;
               if (groupBox->subControls & QStyle::SC_GroupBoxCheckBox) {
                   finalRect = checkBoxRect.united(textRect);
                   finalRect.adjust(ltr ? -4 : 0, 0, ltr ? 0 : 4, 0);
               } else {
                   finalRect = textRect;
               }
               region -= finalRect;
           }
           p->setClipRegion(region);
           proxy()->drawPrimitive(PE_FrameGroupBox, &frame, p, widget);
           p->restore();
       }

       // Draw icon
       if (!groupBox->pixmap.isNull()) {
           p->fillRect(decorationOffset, 0, pixmapRectWidth, pixmapHeight, opt->palette.window().color());
           proxy()->drawItemPixmap(p, QRect(decorationOffset, 0, pixmapRectWidth, pixmapHeight),
                                   Qt::AlignCenter, groupBox->pixmap);
       }

       // Draw title
       if ((groupBox->subControls & QStyle::SC_GroupBoxLabel) && !groupBox->text.isEmpty()) {
           QColor textColor = groupBox->textColor;
           if (textColor.isValid())
               p->setPen(textColor);
           int alignment = int(groupBox->textAlignment);
           if (!proxy()->styleHint(QStyle::SH_UnderlineShortcut, opt, widget))
               alignment |= Qt::TextHideMnemonic;
           proxy()->drawItemText(p, textRect,  Qt::TextShowMnemonic | Qt::AlignHCenter | alignment,
                                 groupBox->palette, groupBox->state & State_Enabled, groupBox->text,
                                 textColor.isValid() ? QPalette::NoRole : QPalette::WindowText);
           if (groupBox->state & State_HasFocus) {
               QStyleOptionFocusRect fropt;
               fropt.QStyleOption::operator=(*groupBox);
               fropt.rect = textRect;
               proxy()->drawPrimitive(PE_FrameFocusRect, &fropt, p, widget);
           }
       }
   } else {
       QCommonStyle::drawComplexControl(cc, opt, p, widget);
   }
   ```
3. Subclass `QGroupBox` and reimplement [`QGroupBox::paintEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#paintEvent) like this:

   ```
   CustomStyle style;
   QPainter painter(this);
   StyleOptionDecoratedGroupBox option;

   initStyleOption(&option);
   option.pixmap = m_pixmap;
   option.offset = m_offset;
   option.leftSpace = m_leftSpace;
   option.rightSpace = m_rightSpace;

   style.drawComplexControl(QStyle::CC_GroupBox, &option, &painter, this);
   ```

**Note:** This solution does not work well when the group box is checkable.

## Example

The solution requires a lot of work, but fortunatelly I have created the necessary classes for you, as well as a complete example of how to use them in your own projects. The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-DecoratedGroupBox).

## Result

The provided example produces the following result:

[image: Window with a decorated group box and radio buttons]

Comment: That's a pretty comprehensive answer from such a simple starting point - excellent work!

Comment: Thank you, @TobySpeight! I really appreciate it! It did seem as a straight-forward task, but I've ended up digging in the code of three Qt classes. :) I trully hope this will spare some work for those, wanting to achieve the same effect.

Comment: This solution is simply great!! Thanks a lot for all your effort!!

Comment: You got my upvote but I still have a tiny critic: You didn't edit the alt text of your image link. As my company's firewall blocks imgur.com (and I was not able to convince the admin to unblock it) I always see these _enter image description here_ links. This is a bit annoying... ;-) (When I learnt HTML decades ago, this was one of the essential recommendations: always to provide an alt text for images - and this seems to be totally forgotten these days.)

Comment: @Scheff, I really appreciate your critic. As a matter of fact, the [qt] tag description says: _We are aiming for high-quality in this tag_. So, as the excellence is in the details, no detail is tiny enough to be left unimproved. After your remark I've added a description to the images on most of my answers. Later I will edit the rest of them. Thank you for reminding me that!

Comment: Maybe it should be explicitly noted that `StyleOptionDecoratedGroupBox` is the name of the new subclass created in step 1). I just spent more time than I am ready to admit searching Qt sources for that type xD And while we're at it the same could be done for `CustomStyle` though with that the name is a bit more obvious imo

Comment: @Raven The Qt classes from the public API begin by convention with Q.

Comment: I know. But given that we are messing with (more or less) Qt intervals I figured this might be an internal QGroupBox class.